# Ubuntu 14.04.4-How to avoid automount of devices

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, fstab, automount

I would like to know how the automount of all the devices startup works. And when I insert a new USB device.

I have a live distro of Ubuntu 14.04.4 (without any GUI, so I can work only with the terminal). I know that several scripts are run from rc0.d rc1.d ... but I can't find anything about automount. I looked also in the fstab file but I didn't find anything.

I don't know where to search for these info.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A server edition of Ubuntu should not automount anything that's not in fstab.  Is that what you have?

Comment: I created a custom version starting from this guide .. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch . I think that by default automount is disabled on my version. I only wanted to know if everything I have to check is in fstab. thank you

Comment: Well, I do not know if automount is disabled or not on your custom version. What you have to check depends on what you have there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man (1) mount

Edit /etc/fstab and add the option "noauto" to the 4th column, something like that:

```
/dev/sda1      /foo/bar    ext4  rw,user,noauto  0 1
```

That's all there is. ;)